# Temp file inside project solution?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is there any way to have temp file inside a temp directory in c# solution and write the bytes into that and after finishing our process delete it without showing that file to users ?

Comment: Yes, there is a way. Any other questions? BTW - please read this: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Your question is not clear. Which bytes do you want to write, and what process are you referring to?

Answer (score 2):

consider using

```
string tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
//Use the file
File.Delete(tempFile);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.IO;

class Logger
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Create (and open) a new temporary file
        var filename = Path.GetTempFileName();
        var file = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Append);

        // Write bytes to it during the programs lifetime...
        file.Write(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 }, 0, 3);

        // Just before closing your program, close and delete it
        file.Close();
        File.Delete(filename);
    }
}
```

Comment: Jakob , Thanks for the reply ,Would you please tell me what is the path to save the file ?
I need to save it inside the solution Directory. Regards,
Bahman.

Comment: @bahman The path to the file is "filename", if you do not wish to use a new file in the temp directory, replace "filename" with the path of your choice. For example `var filename = @"c:\mydir\temp.log"`